# How to validate nested array from JSON response using Postman?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, rest-api, postman, api-automation

I am trying to validate GET method API response JSON using Postman. I have tried some of online suggestion but nothing worked for me.

In my testcase i am validating that List tag is showing or not.

There is some condition in backend, if that condition is true then only "List" will show in response. so, I just wanted to verify that if its true then its showing in response.

```
{
        "Documents": [
            {
                "DocID": "0",
                "DocName": "abc",
                "DocDescription": "abdDescription",
                "DocType": "Document",
                "List": [
                    {
                        "Name": "Full Name",
                        "Value": "Tom"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Mo_Number",
                        "Value": "0001112222"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Address",
                        "Value": "000111222"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Country",
                        "Value": "US"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "City",
                        "Value": "NY"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Occupation",
                        "Value": "Programming"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: What does "showing properly" mean? What data do you expect in the response? Or do you expect a different format? How do you know this response is correct?

Comment: There is some condition in backend, if that condition is true then only "List" will show in response. so, i just wanted to verify that if its true then its showing in response.

Comment: What do you want to validate - what are you trying to check?
Additionally, what have you tried so far and what were the results?

Comment: I have tried code

pm.test('Check nested Id data type', () => {
    _.each(pm.response.json().values, (topLevelItem) => {
        _.each(topLevelItem.values, (nestedItem) => {
            pm.expect(nestedItem.id).to.be.a('string')
        })
    })
})

but its shows pass anyway whether "List" array shows or not

Answer (score 2):

You solution in the comment section:

```javascript
pm.test('Check nested Id data type', () => {
  _.each(pm.response.json().values, (topLevelItem) => {
    _.each(topLevelItem.values, (nestedItem) => {
      pm.expect(nestedItem.id).to.be.a('string')
    });
  });
});
```

has a few problems:

- if there're no values, those loops won't run, so there's nothing to check, therefore it'll pass
- you mention `id` property, but I see no `id` property in your example JSON in your question
- your check is named `Check nested Id data type`, but you're asking (from the comment section):

> There is some condition in backend, if that condition is true then only "List" will show in response. so, I just wanted to verify that if it's true then it's showing in response.

All in all, people are confused because it seems you're asking more than just one question.

---

Going back to the problem of checking that `List` property is in the response. You can check that in JavaScript and Postman like so:

```javascript
const resBody = pm.response.json();

pm.test("Response has 'List' property", function () {
  pm.expect(resBody.Documents[0]).to.have.ownProperty('List');
});
```

You also might want to check it's an object:

```javascript
pm.test("'List' property is object", function () {
  pm.expect(resBody.Documents[0]).to.be.an('object');
});
```

And you said "only" `List`:

```javascript
pm.test("'Documents' has only one property", function () {
  pm.expect(Object.keys(resBody.Documents[0]).length).to.eq(1);
});
```

All three checks might be problematic because they consider only the first `Documents` array item. I'll leave the rest to you, you can edit these checks to check all `Documents` array items if there are more.

I recomment going through Postman documentation, the actually mention all these checks there (and much more) and give you examples. You can check their [Writing tests docs](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/test-scripts/) and also [Chai assertion library](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/).

Answer (score 0):

I have a follow up question on this. What if I would like to store "County's" value in a local variable?

I mean just this "US" part from the following object:

```
                {
                    "Name": "Country",
                    "Value": "US"
                },
```

This is a real challenge because of all these arrays and the fact that "List" array contains objects which have identical elements. So, "Name" and "Value" are repeating 6 times.

But, I do not want to use this method bellow because the order of those objects may change. In this case "Country" is at third position [3], but it could be on [4] or any other position. So not like this bellow:

```
const response = pm.response.json();
const country = response.map(data => data.Documents[0].List[3].Value);
pm.variables.set('extractedCounty', country);
```

I guess that filter function should be used, but I have no idea how.

I am not an expert, so I may made a mistake in this test script I just wrote here, but hopefully you are getting the point.

Thanks in advance.